# Honors Level High School Coursework Curriculum?

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, homeschooling

My wife and I will be homeschooling our son and twin daughters. We're interested in adopting an honors-level mathematics curriculum for secondary students that culminated in calculus AB in 12th grade. Which textbooks on the market (or not) would you math brains recommend for honors level courses in Algebra I, Proof-Heavy Geometry, Algebra II/Trig, and Intro Math Analysis/Precalc. My wife and I both have taken calculus through differential equations and are in science related fields. We'd be able to take a formal approach to teaching the math. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a great question. However, this website is devoted pretty much exclusively to the research concerns of professional mathematicians, and this sort of question is not of the type we cater to, unfortunately. I will however migrate this to a more suitable StackExchange site, and I wish you and your family success.

Comment: Some of the freely available SMSG books I listed in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122421/getting-the-grip-of-geometry-and-algebra-books-and-resources-for-a-beginner) are worth looking at. See also the suggestions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661875/how-to-get-a-top-notch-math-education-high-school-level-online?) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127814/preparing-for-university-and-advanced-mathematics?).

Answer (score 2):

Check into the courses offered by [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/). They get good reviews from the homeschoolers I am in contact with. Although their description does not mention honors-level or AB, they train students for competitions, and their materials include the rigor you desire.